# Setting classpath from bat file doesnt work

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

So when i manually start my bat file that is on desktop, it works because executing a bat file via its icon uses directory of the icon(file) which is "C:\Users\Michael\Desktop".

```
set CLASSPATH = %~dp0 &:: %~dp0 stands for the directory of the bat file
java InitArray 5 0 4 &:: comment
pause
```

When i run the bat file above(InitArray.bat) from its desktop icon, it works.

```
java InitArray 5 0 4 &:: comment
pause
```

When i run the bat file above(test.bat) from its desktop icon, it works.

But when i run InitArray.bat from task scheduler, it uses the directory "C:\WINDOWS\system32". But that shouldnt be a problem because the first thing the bat file does is "set CLASSPATH = C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\".

Here is the result of task scheduler trying to run InitArray.bat.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>set CLASSPATH = C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\

C:\WINDOWS\system32>java InitArray 5 0 4
Error: Could not find or load main class InitArray

C:\WINDOWS\system32>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Now, i know i can fix this issue by adding "C:\Users\Desktop\" to environment variable CLASSPATH. But i shouldnt need to do that since i am manually setting classpath to desktop in the first line of my bat file before trying to run the java class.

Comment: Your code is filled with illegal stuff, why would anyone read it? Remove ALL MALFORMED `lable`. They start with `::` which tells us you copied this stuff.

Comment: `set CLASSPATH = %~dp0` sets a variable called `CLASSPATH` + _SPACE_, so remove the spaces around the `=`-sign... Ah, and remove the `&::` stuff (it is often fine, but it can cause terrible problems); for comments, use [`rem`](http://ss64.com/nt/rem.html)...

Comment: @catcat No i didnt copy this stuff. i am not an expert in dos programming. I thought &:: was just a harmless comment just like // in java.

Comment: Alternatively, `cd %~dp0`. Or `java -cp "%~dp0" InitArray 5 0 4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting a variable, everthing from the beginning of the variable name, until the last typed character is used as part of the variable name, before the `=` and value after the `=`. So:

```
set CLASSPATH = Somepath
```

Will end up with a variable name `%CLASSPATH %` (note the trailing space) and value `Somepath` (note the starting space.

Even if you add an accidental space after the value, it will become part of it, So this
`set CLASSPATH=Somepath` will end up with value with a trailing space `Somepath`

So always leave no space before or after the `=` and always enclose your code in double quotes to eliminate whitespace:

```
set "CLASSPATH=Somepath"
```

or in your actual case, it should look like:

```
set "CLASSPATH=%~dp0"
```

Comment: I guess i could use echo and pause to debug my bat programs (print values of variables). Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set the CLASSPATH along with the java execution command or change directory using cd command.

```
cd /path_to_required_folder   // set current directory
java -cp /classpath_location/ test.jar your.package.MainClass [args...]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I didnt want to use cd command because i want the bat file to be dynamic(run no matter where the user moves the folder that includes the bat file and java class file).